# get django value from django queryset where column name is a variable

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a database with some column names set up as abbreviated month names - the same as you see in this dictionary:

```
months = {'jan':0, 'feb':0, 'mar':0, 'apr':0, 'may':0, 'jun':0, 'jul':0, 'aug':0, 'sep':0, 'oct':0, 'nov':0, 'dec':0}
```

I'm trying to get the integer value stored in the db where the dictionary key is the same as the column name and store it in y

```
>>> for i in Somedb.objects.all():
...  for key, value in months.items():
...   y = i.key
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Somedb' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Anyone know how to do this? For example, in the above loop - `i.jan` would return the value I need for January.

Cheers, Arthur

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `key='jan'`, and you want to get `obj.jan`, you can use Python's [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
getattr(obj, key)
```